# R Convert List Into Data.Frame or Table

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data.table

```
list1 = list(
  c(4,5,6,7,1,1,1,1,3,1,3,3),
  c(3,4,5,6,2,2,2,2,1,4,2,1),
  c(1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,3,2,1,1),
  c(5,6,7,8,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,3),
  c(2,3,4,5,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1)
)

data1=data.frame("ID"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5),
"Time"=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
"Grade"=c(4,5,6,7,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5),
"Class"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
"Score"=c(3,1,3,3,1,4,2,1,3,2,1,1,4,4,4,3,2,1,2,1))
```

I have 'list1' Each item in 'list1' equals to a single individual's Grade, Class, Score for 4 years.
So 'list1' has 5 students and 12 records for each student (4 records for every of three variables, Grade and Class and Score). I wish to turn 'list1' into 'data1' that is a long data file where 'ID' equals to the list item number in 'list1'. Time equals to time of the record (every student has 4 time measures), Grade equals to the first 4 data points in ALL elements in list1, Class the next 4, and Score the last 4.

Sample output is shown turning 'list1' into desired output 'data1'.

This data set is HUGE so I am hoping for a efficient approach to doing this conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it'll be efficient but it's concise:

```
setDT(list1)
# could also do something like paste0('student', 1:5) for clarity,
#   and adjust patterns() below accordingly
setnames(list1, paste0(1:5))
# 4 = # of values of Time
list1[ , colid := rep(c('Grade', 'Class', 'Score'), each = 4L)]
# 3 = # of columns "stacked" in each student's column initially
list1[ , Time := rep(1:4, 3L)]
# first, reshape long
list1[ , melt(.SD, measure.vars = patterns('^[0-9]+'), variable.name = 'ID',
              variable.factor = FALSE)
       # now, reshape to the final format
       ][ , dcast(.SD, ID + Time ~ colid, value.var = 'value')]
#         ID  Time Class Grade Score
#     <char> <int> <num> <num> <num>
#  1:      1     1     1     4     3
#  2:      1     2     1     5     1
#  3:      1     3     1     6     3
#  4:      1     4     1     7     3
#  5:      2     1     2     3     1
#  6:      2     2     2     4     4
#  7:      2     3     2     5     2
#  8:      2     4     2     6     1
#  9:      3     1     1     1     3
# 10:      3     2     1     2     2
# 11:      3     3     1     3     1
# 12:      3     4     1     4     1
# 13:      4     1     1     5     4
# 14:      4     2     1     6     4
# 15:      4     3     1     7     4
# 16:      4     4     1     8     3
# 17:      5     1     2     2     2
# 18:      5     2     2     3     1
# 19:      5     3     2     4     2
# 20:      5     4     2     5     1
#         ID  Time Class Grade Score
```

The inefficiency would come from having two operations here.

The approach of building the table skeleton first, then populating it *may* be faster, like this:

```
# 4 = # of Times per ID&Column (assuming your table is rectangular)
out = CJ(ID = 1:length(list1), Time = 1:4)
# relies on ID being an integer, so that ID = 1 --> list1[[1]]
#   gives ID=1's data
out[ , by = ID, c('Grade', 'Class', 'Score') := {
  as.data.table(matrix(list1[[ .BY$ID ]], ncol = 3L))
}]
```

It may be that `as.data.table` is also inefficient but this code is more readable than the alternative:

```
out = CJ(ID = 1:length(list1), Time = 1:4)
out[ , by = ID, c('Grade', 'Class', 'Score') := {
  student_data = list1[[.BY$ID]]
  lapply(1:3, function(j) student_data[4L*(j-1) + 1:4])
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another base solution that is very fast. It is less elegant but the idea is that we minimize memory use by filling out a matrix with a loop.

```
mat = matrix(0, nrow = length(list1) * 4L, ncol = 5L, dimnames = list(NULL, c("ID", "Time", "Grade", "Class", "Score")))

rw = 0L
times = 1:4

for (i in seq_along(list1)) {
  l = list1[[i]]
  new_rw = length(l) / 3
  inds = seq_len(new_rw) + rw

  mat[inds, 1L] = i
  mat[inds, 2L] = times
  mat[inds, 3:5] = matrix(l, ncol = 3L)

  rw = new_rw + rw
}
```

And here is a faster way which unlists and then makes a matrix by selecting our unlisted elements in a certain order:

```
n = length(list1)
matrix(unlist(list1, use.names = FALSE)[rep(rep(1:4, n) + 12 * rep(0:(n-1L), each = 4), 3) + rep(c(0, 4, 8), each = n * 4L)], ncol = 3)
```

Then finally, if you still need speed, `Rcpp` can be used:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(
  " NumericMatrix rcpp_combo(List x) {
  NumericMatrix out(x.size() * 4, 5);
  int init = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    NumericVector tmp = x(i);
    int ID = i + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      int ind = j + init;

      out(ind, 0) = ID;
      out(ind, 1) = j + 1;
      out(ind, 2) = tmp(j);
      out(ind, 3) = tmp(4 + j);
      out(ind, 4) = tmp(8 + j);
    }
    init += 4;
  }
  return(out);
}"
)
rcpp_combo(list1)
```

Using @Sathish's benchmarks, these methods are between 0.05 and 2 seconds.

```
big_list <- unlist(mget(x = rep('list1', 100000)), recursive = FALSE)

system.time(rcpp_combo(big_list))
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.07    0.00    0.06 

system.time({
  n = length(big_list)
  mat2 = matrix(unlist(big_list, use.names = FALSE)[rep(rep(1:4, n) + 12 * rep(0:(n-1L), each = 4), 3) + rep(c(0, 4, 8), each = n * 4L)], ncol = 3)
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.20    0.02    0.22 

big_list <- unlist(mget(x = rep('list1', 100000)), recursive = FALSE)
system.time({
mat = matrix(0, nrow = length(big_list) * 4L, ncol = 5L, dimnames = list(NULL, c("ID", "Time", "Grade", "Class", "Score")))
rw = 0L
times = 1:4
for (i in seq_along(big_list)) {
  l = big_list[[i]]
  new_rw = length(l) / 3
  inds = seq_len(new_rw) + rw
  mat[inds, 1L] = i
  mat[inds, 2L] = times
  mat[inds, 3:5] = matrix(l, ncol = 3L)
  rw = new_rw + rw
}
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##   2.08    0.03    2.21
```

Answer (score 1):

One `purrr` and `dplyr` solution could be:

```
map_dfr(.x = list1, 
        ~ as.data.frame(matrix(.x, 4, 3)) %>%
         setNames(c("Grade", "Class", "Score")), .id = "ID") %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(Time = 1:n())

   ID    Grade Class Score  Time
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1 1         4     1     3     1
 2 1         5     1     1     2
 3 1         6     1     3     3
 4 1         7     1     3     4
 5 2         3     2     1     1
 6 2         4     2     4     2
 7 2         5     2     2     3
 8 2         6     2     1     4
 9 3         1     1     3     1
10 3         2     1     2     2
11 3         3     1     1     3
12 3         4     1     1     4
13 4         5     1     4     1
14 4         6     1     4     2
15 4         7     1     4     3
16 4         8     1     3     4
17 5         2     2     2     1
18 5         3     2     1     2
19 5         4     2     2     3
20 5         5     2     1     4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, we can iterate over the index of `list1` and create a dataframe for each list.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(list1), function(i) 
        data.frame(ID = i, Time = 1:4, Grade = list1[[i]][1:4], 
                    Class = list1[[i]][5:8], Score = list1[[i]][9:12])))

#   ID Time Grade Class Score
#1   1    1     4     1     3
#2   1    2     5     1     1
#3   1    3     6     1     3
#4   1    4     7     1     3
#5   2    1     3     2     1
#6   2    2     4     2     4
#7   2    3     5     2     2
#8   2    4     6     2     1
#9   3    1     1     1     3
#10  3    2     2     1     2
#11  3    3     3     1     1
#12  3    4     4     1     1
#13  4    1     5     1     4
#14  4    2     6     1     4
#15  4    3     7     1     4
#16  4    4     8     1     3
#17  5    1     2     2     2
#18  5    2     3     2     1
#19  5    3     4     2     2
#20  5    4     5     2     1
```

Comment: this works great in a small set of my data. but do you know of data.table solution since it seems that it may take several days (my data has over 1 million elements in the list)

Comment: I see. Please check @MichaelChirico's `data.table` solution if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using 10 Million data points

**Data:**

```
list1 = list(
  c(4,5,6,7,1,1,1,1,3,1,3,3),
  c(3,4,5,6,2,2,2,2,1,4,2,1),
  c(1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,3,2,1,1),
  c(5,6,7,8,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,3),
  c(2,3,4,5,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1))

big_list <- unlist(mget(x = rep('list1', 100000)), recursive = FALSE)
```

**Code: - Using Base-R: `split()`**

```
system.time({
  col_levels <- rep(c('Grade', 'Class', 'Score'), each = 4)

  for(x in seq_along(big_list)){
    big_list[[x]] <- do.call('cbind', list(ID = x, Time = 1:4, 
                                        do.call('cbind', split(big_list[[x]], col_levels))))
  }

  final_df <- do.call('rbind', big_list)      
})

# user  system elapsed 
# 82.86    0.31   83.78
```

**Comparison: Using `data.table`**

@MichaelChirico

```
library('data.table')
system.time({
  # 4 = # of Times per ID&Column (assuming your table is rectangular)
  out = CJ(ID = 1:length(big_list), Time = 1:4)
  # relies on ID being an integer, so that ID = 1 --> list1[[1]]
  #   gives ID=1's data
  out[ , by = ID, c('Grade', 'Class', 'Score') := {
    as.data.table(matrix(big_list[[ .BY$ID ]], ncol = 3L))
  }]
})

# user  system elapsed 
# 76.22    0.25   76.80
```

**Output**

```
dim(final_df)
# [1] 2000000      5

head(final_df)
#      ID Time Class Grade Score
# [1,]  1    1     1     4     3
# [2,]  1    2     1     5     1
# [3,]  1    3     1     6     3
# [4,]  1    4     1     7     3
# [5,]  2    1     2     3     1
# [6,]  2    2     2     4     4
```